# how to get field name of class in java

Tags: java, json, dynamic, reflection, field

Hello all sorry my language is Bad!

This is my code:

```
MyCustomClass temp = new MyCustomClass();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    temp.ID = obj.getInt("ID");
    temp.PicName = obj.getString("PicName");
    temp.PicURL = obj.getString("PicURL");
    Items.add(temp);
}
```

I would like to take this dynamic

Something like this

```
MyCustomClass temp = new MyCustomClass();
Field[] myFields= MyCustomClass.class.getFields();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    for(int j=0;j<myFields.lenghth();j++)
    {
        myFields[j]=obj.getString(myFields[j].toString());
        Items.add(temp);
    }
}
```

How to do it?

*Name of jason fields = Name of MycustomClass Fields

Comment: You can use the `Gson` library instead of `json-simple`. `Gson` can convert JSON strings to Java objects and the other way around

Comment: Do you use a json library like `jackson`? With jackson you can set up your `MyCustomClass` Pojo with annotations and which fields should be parsed.

Comment: Does any of the answers helps you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) will do all this for you.

```
static class TestClass {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}

@Test
public void gson() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    TestClass[] item = gson.fromJson("[{'id': 1, 'name': 'testclass'}]", TestClass[].class);
    assertThat(item[0].id, is(1));
    assertThat(item[0].name, is("testclass"));
    assertThat(item.length, is(1));
}

@Test
public void jackson() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapepr = new ObjectMapper();
    TestClass[] item = jacksonObjectMapepr.readValue("[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"testclass\"}]", TestClass[].class);
    assertThat(item[0].id, is(1));
    assertThat(item[0].name, is("testclass"));
    assertThat(item.length, is(1));
}
```

However to answer your question, you can look up what each field with [`getDeclaredField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)). But you will have to do quite some work to handle all the type mapping.

```
@Test
public void sillyWayIDontRecommend() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    TestClass[] item = new TestClass[1];

    JsonArray array = new JsonParser().parse("[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"testclass\"}]").getAsJsonArray();
    for(int i = 0; i<array.size(); i++) {
        item[i] = new TestClass();

        JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : object.entrySet()) {
            Field field = TestClass.class.getDeclaredField(entry.getKey());
            if(field.getType().equals(int.class)) {
                field.setInt(item[i], entry.getValue().getAsInt());
            } else {
                field.set(item[i], entry.getValue().getAsString());
            }
        }
    }

    assertThat(item[0].id, is(1));
    assertThat(item[0].name, is("testclass"));
    assertThat(item.length, is(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With jackson library you are able to set up your Pojos directly with json annotations and you are able to convert your JSON strings directly to java objects.

**A generic way for parsing can be something like that:**

```
public static <T> T deserialize(T t, Class<T> clazz, String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    }
```

`T` - is your object and return type

`clazz` - is your Pojo

`json` - is your json String

**You can call the method like this:**

```
MyCustomClass myCustomClass= new MyCustomClass();
myCustomClass= JsonUtil.deserialize(myCustomClass, MyCustomClass.class, json);
```

**Your Pojo can look like this:**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties // ignores properties from json String which are not in your Pojo
public class MyCustomClass {

    @JsonProperty("anotherNameIfFieldNameIsNotEqual")
    private String picName;
    private String picURL;

    public String getPicName() {
        return picName;
    }
    public void setPicName(String picName) {
        this.picName = picName;
    }
    public String getPicURL() {
        return picURL;
    }
    public void setPicURL(String picURL) {
        this.picURL= picURL;
    }
}
```

**And this is the maven dependency you need:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

---

[Documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation) and [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all class field with this construction:

```
Class class = ...//obtain class object
Field[] methods = class.getFields();
```

With your class it's:

```
MyCustomClass temp = new MyCustomClass();
Field[] methods = temp.getFields();
```